# CSV file data not replaced in request while running multiple test data for API in POSTMAN

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am testing my API with postman app and list of requests. The list of different requests are placed in CSV file in below format:

```
 path value
 post "myrequestdata1"
 post "myrequestdata2"
 ...  ...
```

but during my run it takes only the request which i mentioned initial test.

My request body :

```
 {
     "requestID": "xxxxxxx",
     "clientRequestHandle": "YYYYYYY",
     "items":{
                          "AppNumber": "105",
                        "AppId": "105",
                        "AppInfo": [{}, {}]
 }
  }
```

my csv data represents:

```
 path, value
 post,"{  "requestID": "xxxxxxx",  "clientRequestHandle": "YYYYYYY",  "items":{ "AppNumber": "105", "AppId": "105", "AppInfo": [{}, {}] } }"
 post,"{  "requestID": "xxxxxxx",  "clientRequestHandle": "YYYYYYY",  "items":{ "AppNumber": "106", "AppId": "106", "AppInfo": [{}, {}] } }"
 post,"{  "requestID": "xxxxxxx",  "clientRequestHandle": "YYYYYYY",  "items":{ "AppNumber": "107", "AppId": "107", "AppInfo": [{}, {}] } }"
```

Folks help me on this...

Comment: As I understand, you have a file with values which you use to replace variables in request template during collection runner execution, right? Could you please share Postman request which you use as template? And could you share part of your file?

Comment: @Stepan you are rit. please find my request: {
  "requestID": "xxxxxxx",
  "clientRequestHandle": "YYYYYYY",
  "items":{
                            "AppNumber": "105",
                            "AppId": "105",
                            "AppInfo": [{}, {}]
}
}      and my csv data :  path, value
post,"{  "requestID": "xxxxxxx",  "clientRequestHandle": "YYYYYYY",  "items":{ "AppNumber": "105", "AppId": "105", "AppInfo": [{}, {}] } }"

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape quotes symbols like this in your csv-file:

```
path, value
post,"{  ""requestID"": ""xxxxxxx"",  ""clientRequestHandle"": ""YYYYYYY"",  ""items"":{ ""AppNumber"": ""105"", ""AppId"": ""105"", ""AppInfo"": [{}, {}] } }"
post,"{  ""requestID"": ""xxxxxxx"",  ""clientRequestHandle"": ""YYYYYYY"",  ""items"":{ ""AppNumber"": ""106"", ""AppId"": ""106"", ""AppInfo"": [{}, {}] } }"
post,"{  ""requestID"": ""xxxxxxx"",  ""clientRequestHandle"": ""YYYYYYY"",  ""items"":{ ""AppNumber"": ""107"", ""AppId"": ""107"", ""AppInfo"": [{}, {}] } }"
```

and use the following Request Body in request:

```
{{value}}
```

Comment: let me try this and get back to you